# Clone a class instance, changing just a few of the properties

Tags: f#, clone

I was wondering if in F# there is some sugar for cloning a class instance changing just one or a few of the properties.

I know in F# it is possible with records:

```
let p2 = {p1 with Y = 0.0}
```

Comment: I resolve to OO in order to keep my code tidy and functions organized.

Comment: @GuyCoder: "Do use properties and methods for operations intrinsic to types. 
This is called out specifically because some people from a functional programming background avoid 
the use of object oriented programming together, preferring a module containing a set of functions 
defining the intrinsic functions related to a type (e.g. length foo rather than foo.Length). [..] In general, in F#, the use of object-oriented programming is preferred as a 
software engineering device..." (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to simulate copy-and-update expressions for classes is with a copy constructor taking optional args.

```
type Person(first, last, age) =
  new (prototype: Person, ?first, ?last, ?age) =
    Person(defaultArg first prototype.First, 
           defaultArg last prototype.Last, 
           defaultArg age prototype.Age)
  member val First = first
  member val Last = last
  member val Age = age

let john = Person("John", "Doe", 45)
let jane = Person(john, first="Jane")
```

EDIT

You didn't ask for this, but in many cases making the class mutable results in clearer code:

```
type Person(first, last, age) =
  member val First = first with get, set
  member val Last = last with get, set
  member val Age = age with get, set
  member this.Clone() = this.MemberwiseClone() :?> Person

let john = Person("John", "Doe", 45)
let jane = john.Clone() in jane.First <- "Jane"
```

Comment: Good idea. I am however surprised there isn't an idiomatic expression to achieve that.

Comment: I _think_ it's fair to say the OO aspects of F# were more or less copied over from the mainstream .NET languages. Although, there are a few additions—mostly to support a more functional style—such as object expressions and immutability by default. But overall, the OO story on .NET remains mostly unchanged in F#.

Comment: AFAIK Copy-and-update expressions have been introduced in Scala to encourage the use of classes with immutable properties. Copy-and-update encourage the creation of a new instances even if only one property has been updated without having to declare everything in the create-from-scratch constructor. Along this line of thoughts, I expected F# to have idomatic copy-and-update expressions. Anyhow, your solution is great. I accepted it and thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. In my view, copy-and-update for classes wouldn't provide a distinct benefit in F#. There are already records, which support this. If you intend to change properties frequently you could define a `Clone` method and make them mutable. I added an example to my answer so you could compare the two approaches.

Comment: @Daniel I really think copy-and-update for classes would provide a huge benefit. It would make interop with for example WSDL and other services amazingly easy and make F# the "go to language" for data interop. I even think we should go one step further and make a *pattern-match-copy* feature with operators to map to certain property names. Type safety in transformations of unstructured or ambivalent data types.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to wrap a record in a class. Some thing like

```
type PersonState = { FirstName : string; LastName : string; }

type Person private (state : PersonState) =

    new (firstName, lastName) = 
        Person({ FirstName = firstName; LastName = lastName })

    member this.WithFirstName value =  
        Person { state with FirstName = value } 

    member this.WithLastName value  =  
        Person { state with LastName = value } 

    member this.FirstName with get () = state.FirstName
    member this.LastName with get () = state.LastName
```

Use as

```
let JohnDoe = Person("John", "Doe")
let JaneDoe = JohnDoe.WithFirstName "Jane" 
let JaneLastName = JaneDoe.LastName
```

This approach avoids explicit cloning and mutability.